# OpenTelemetry JVM and System metrics

Tags: monitoring, metrics, open-telemetry, observability

I have used micrometer.io for most of my career to collect metrics. One of the coolest micrometer features is binding to collect information about the host system and jvm: https://micrometer.io/docs/ref/jvm on the basis of which it was possible to run the Grafana dashboard without much effort: https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/4701

Currently, I am starting to learn about OpenTelemetry, but I cannot find a description of the above functionalities. I do not want to use instrumentation, I want to depend on a manual definition of what is to be measured. Can you show me a way to do this? How to easily manually provide system/JVM metrics?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an equivalent of Prometheus simpleclient\_hotspot with Opentelemetry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73908450/is-there-an-equivalent-of-prometheus-simpleclient-hotspot-with-opentelemetry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Is there an equivalent of Prometheus simpleclient_hotspot with Opentelemetry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73908450/is-there-an-equivalent-of-prometheus-simpleclient-hotspot-with-opentelemetry).

You can use `opentelemetry-java-instrumentation` and manually register JVM metrics observers.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think such a component exist in OTel, see:

Metrics API spec: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/blob/main/specification/metrics/api.md

Metrics SDK spec: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/blob/main/specification/metrics/sdk.md

Comment: That's a little bit sad. I thought that such a thing would be basic. If there is no official solution I wonder how other people approach this problem. Usually, JVM/process metrics help a lot. Do people write their own solutions? Or maybe use (and bridge) other libraries for this .

Comment: @dsinczak were you able to find a way to collect jvm metrics using opentelemetry?

Comment: @NDeepakPrasath no, we switched to the Prometheus client for metrics. There was no point adding more complexity if there are tools that just do the job.