# Is there an equivalent of Prometheus simpleclient_hotspot with Opentelemetry?

Tags: java, jvm, prometheus, open-telemetry

I'm looking to migrate a Java app that exposes metrics by using Prometheus APIs to OpenTelemetry APIs.

The app custom metrics part is okay but with Prometheus API, we used to use `DefaultExports.initialize()` which comes from *simpleclient_hotspot* dependency and generates automatically a bunch of metrics of the JVM itself like the followings:

```
# HELP jvm_memory_bytes_max Max (bytes) of a given JVM memory area.
# TYPE jvm_memory_bytes_max gauge
jvm_memory_bytes_max{area="heap",} 3.221225472E9
jvm_memory_bytes_max{area="nonheap",} -1.0
# HELP jvm_memory_bytes_init Initial bytes of a given JVM memory area.
# TYPE jvm_memory_bytes_init gauge
jvm_memory_bytes_init{area="heap",} 3.221225472E9
jvm_memory_bytes_init{area="nonheap",} 7667712.0
```

Is there an equivalent library or a way to accomplish the same with OpenTelemetry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `opentelemetry-java-instrumentation` project publishes a library for collecting JVM runtime metrics. Source code lives [here](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/tree/main/instrumentation/runtime-metrics/library), and publishes to maven coordinates `io.opentelemetry.instrumentation:opentelemetry-runtime-metrics:<version>`.

To use, create an `OpenTelemetrySdk` instance, and initialize the various observers you need:

```
OpenTelemetry opentelemetry = OpenTelemetrySdk.builder().build();
MemoryPools.registerObservers(opentelemetry);
BufferPools.registerObservers(opentelemetry);
Classes.registerObservers(opentelemetry);
Cpu.registerObservers(opentelemetry);
Threads.registerObservers(opentelemetry);
GarbageCollector.registerObservers(opentelemetry);
```

Comment: As of today, there is slightly less metrics available and the name are not the same which makes the transition not as smooth but the essential is here.

Comment: I'll add that if you're using auto-instrumentation java agent, this comes out of the box without having to do any code.